# Plotting a line for each row in a Dataframe with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got the following dataframe describing the age structure in different german districts:

[image]

I would like to plot one line per row with ggplot in R. An easy solution via matplot in R is:

```
matplot(t(df61[,-c(1,2)], type="l"))
```

which yields:

[image]

But how is it working with ggplot. I understood, that I have to transform the dataframe into a flat form:

```
library("reshape2")
df61_long <- melt(df61[,-2], id.vars = "NAME")
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I thought that the solution via ggplot should be something like:

```
ggplot(df61_long, aes(x = "variable", y = "value")) + geom_line(aes(colors = "NAME"))
```

which, however, yields an empty coordinate system. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible, so I made my own:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(cat = LETTERS[1:6], VAR1 = runif(6), VAR2 = runif(6), VAR3 = runif(6), VAR4 = runif(6))
df_melted = melt(df, id.vars = 'cat')
```

In your code:

```
ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = 'variable', y = 'value')) + geom_line(aes(color = 'cat'))
```

there are a number of issues:

- There is no `colors` aesthetic, should be `color`.
- Aesthetics should not be passed as strings to `aes`. Use `aes_string` for that.
- You need an additional aes in this case, `group`.

This code works:

```
ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(color = cat, group = cat))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that worked! I am still not sure when to use the group=... parameter. I thought that color=... would do the grouping.